# Automatic Image zoom with easy and out

Tags: javascript, transition

Can someone say me how i can do something like that on this page:

[marriottgrandcaymanbeachhouse.com](http://marriottgrandcaymanbeachhouse.com/)

I want to do like on this  website an automatic zoom of my images without hover or click. A ease and out zooming function that is infinite.

I use this class but i don`t know how i activate it.

```
    .zoom.visible > img {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: move;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -o-animation-direction: alternate;
  -ms-transform-origin: middle center;
  transform-origin: middle center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: middle center;
  -o-transform-origin: middle center;
  -moz-transform-origin: middle center;
}
```

Unfortunately i dont`t know what to search for in google and i hope some can help to push me in the right direction or has a code example for me.

Comment: Which images on that page?! How do you expect to trigger the zoom if you don't want to acknowledge an event such as `click` or `hover` ? Magic?!

Comment: for example the first image on this page.. this image is slightly moving

Comment: On which page?!  The image I see on your example is a woman with a hat.  It is already full-screen-width?!

Comment: exactly that image and if you look closly for a while you see that this image is slighty zooming in and out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the necessary parts out of the website, this is what you need

CSS:

```
.zoom.visible > img {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: move;
    animation-name: move;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -o-animation-direction: alternate;
    -ms-transform-origin: middle center;
    transform-origin: middle center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: middle center;
    -o-transform-origin: middle center;
    -moz-transform-origin: middle center;
}
.zoom > img {
    height: auto!important;
    width: 100%!important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    text-indent: -9999px;
    ms-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -o-transform: scale(1.15);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.15);
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -o-transform: scale(1.15);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.15);
  }
}
```

Which works on an image with the same HTML structure as this :

```
<div class="zoom visible imagen1" style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px; height: 678px;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt="" />
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9hwk7jtu/